# How to solve simple Diophantine equation coming from solutions in modulos.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Given $x,y,z$ and knowing that all variables are integers, how could one uniquely solve:

> $$xa-yb = z$$
>   ($\text{mod}\; xy$, of course).

I came across this when trying to solve a modulo question on a competition and I realized I always just guessed when I had the answer down to that form and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the extended Euclidean Algorithm; see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

First solve ax + by = d where d is the GCD, then multiply by z/d to get the solutions to ax + by = z.

Comment: Can you explain how you would apply it, given arbitrary $x,y,z$?